# Как лучше организовать синхронизацию, через 2 логических или одну интеджер? 3 варианта возможны

Tags: delphi, инспекция-кода

```
procedure TNewThread.Execute;
var
  LocalIndex: integer;
  data: Tstringlist;
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
begin
  marriage := false;
  if not Work then
    exit;
  if Terminated then
    exit;
  while Work do
  begin
    CS.Enter;
    InterlockedIncrement(GlobalIndex);
    if GlobalIndex < Accounts.Count then
      LocalIndex := GlobalIndex
    else
      Work := false;
    CS.Leave;
    if Work then
    begin
      FPas := Accounts[LocalIndex];
      data := Tstringlist.create;
      data.Add('login=' + login);
      data.Add('password=' + LowerCase(md5UTF8(trim(FPas))));
      HTTP := TIdHTTP.create;
      HTTP.ConnectTimeout := Form1.FConnectTimeout;
      HTTP.ReadTimeOut := Form1.FReadTimeOut;
      HTTP.HandleRedirects := false;
      HTTP.Request.UserAgent := DefUserAgent;
      HTTP.ProtocolVersion := pv1_1;
      HTTP.Request.Referer := Refer;
      try
        try
          brut_result := 'ok' = HTTP.Post(Url, data);
        except
          marriage := True;
        end;
      finally
        FreeAndNil(HTTP);
        FreeAndNil(data);
        Synchronize(Sync);
      end;
    end;
  end;
  Terminate;
end;

procedure TNewThread.Sync;
begin
  Form1.SpinEditPotok.Value := Thread;
  Application.ProcessMessages;

  if (marriage) then
  begin
    NoCheckFile.Add(FPas);
    Form1.SpinEditError.Value := Form1.SpinEditError.value + 1;
    Application.ProcessMessages;
    Form1.ProgressBar1.Position := Form1.ProgressBar1.Position + 1;
  end
  else
  begin
    if (brut_result) then
    begin
      Work := false;
      FPause := True;
      Form1.SpinEditError.value := 0;
      Form1.MemoResult.Lines.Add(login + ';' + Fpas);
      Application.ProcessMessages;
      Form1.SpinEditGood.Value := Form1.SpinEditGood.Value + 1;
      Form1.SpinEditPotok.Value := Thread;
      Form1.googhit;
      FPause := False;
    end
    else
    begin
      Form1.ProgressBar1.Position := Form1.ProgressBar1.Position + 1;
    end;
  end;
  if (Thread = 0) and (Form1.SpinEditError.value > 0) then
    Reload
  else if (Thread = 0) and (Form1.SpinEditError.value = 0) and (FPause = False) then
    Form1.Start1.Click;
end;
```

старт потоков

```
for Thread := 0 to FThreads do
      TNewThread.Create(false);
```

Нормально ли использовать две логические переменные или же лучше организовать через одну переменную integer и case?

Comment: обнулите локальные переменные `data` и `HTTP` в начале функции `Execute`. Вам действительно нужно их создание *внутри* цикла?

Comment: Я задумался... И где их объявить? В привате потока? Потоков то много. Как то мимо этот момент пролетел. Благодарю, обдумаю. Я считал, что локально созданный как бы более потоко-безопасный.

Comment: локальные переменные - нормально, но, возможно, Вас устроит их создание не внутри `while`, а снаружи

Comment: Логика пострадает же. finally переделывать тогда. удалять тогда тоже вне цикла

Comment: не получалось форматировать

Comment: что такое `work`?

Comment: сорри, логическая.

Comment: синхронизацию через события делайте, чтобы поток не знал, ничего о форме. Критические секции если нужны то в `try-finally`, интерлок вынести оттуда. хттп-клиенты и т.п. зачем в цикле создавать?

Comment: ну он отработал - послал результат и перезоздался по новой, а ошибки валят в эксепшене и те акки перезаливаются. Как интерлок вынести? Он же отсчитывает глобальную переменную. Потоков то много? Не пойму.

Comment: ну обычный `inc` можно было в КС запихать, но interlocked атомарен и потокобезопасен, [для этого и предназначен](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms683614(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: там еще говорят класс  `TInterlocked` появился с некоторых пор

Comment: С обычным проскакивали дубли, а с интерлокед - нет. и наоборот с интерлокед без кс тоже дубли.